# Can we identify these Harry Potter Lego microfigures?

Tags: harry-potter, lego

The new Lego Hogwarts castle set comes with [4 minifigures of the four founders of Hogwarts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/206512/on-what-did-lego-base-the-appearance-of-the-new-hogwarts-minifigs) and 12 microfigures of various HP characters, from Harry to Filch. The only problem is I can't make out which microfigure is which. (Some are obvious - Harry and Umbridge. The rest are less so.)

[image: First row - five figures]
[image: Second row - four figures]
[image: Third row - five figures]
[image: Fourth row - three figures]

Please identify the microfigures with their identifying features (I. e., not only because the manual says so, but what makes this character look like this - with Harry it's obvious because of the glasses.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In rows from top to bottom, and numbered 1 to n from left to right:

#### First row

1. Harry Potter. Dark hair, glasses, what may be a hint of a scar.
2. Ron Weasley. Red hair, Gryffindor uniform.
3. Hermione Granger. Brunette, Gryffindor uniform, next to Harry and Ron.
4. Neville Longbottom? Gryffindor uniform, obviously not a Weasley from the hair; Neville is arguably the next most important Gryffindor student other than the Trio.
5. Draco Malfoy. Blonde/white hair, Slytherin uniform.

#### Second row

1. Parvati Patil? Darker-skinned than the other Gryffindors, and Parvati is the only Gryffindor student whose name suggests she's not Caucasian.
2. Cedric Diggory? Hufflepuff uniform. Not (m)any other Hufflepuffs of note.
3. Crabbe or Goyle? Slytherin uniform, appears to be male from the hair, not sure who else it would be.
4. Luna Lovegood. Blonde, Ravenclaw uniform.

#### Third row

1. Albus Dumbledore. Colourful robes, grey hair and beard.
2. Minerva McGonagall. This figure is female (note the shape of the lips), and this row appears to be Hogwarts teachers/staff. McGonagall is a more important female teacher than the others.
3. Severus Snape. Long black hair, black clothing.
4. Remus Lupin. Red-brown hair, facial hair, wearing a suit.
5. Argus Filch. Balding on top, long grey hair on the sides; apparently Filch is included, and this was the only unclaimed spot.

#### Fourth row

1. Voldemort. White skin, bald, wearing green (snake-like) clothing.
2. Bellatrix Lestrange. Female, dark-haired; Bellatrix is the next most powerful/important villain after Voldemort.
3. Dolores Umbridge. The clothes are pink, and she's in the row with other villains from the books.

Comment: #5 in the third row must be Filch, as he's supposed to be included. I have no clue what identifies him though..

Comment: Cho is a Ravenclaw.  The only Hufflepuff I recall is Cedric Diggory.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus And pompous Ernie.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus You're right. Not sure why I always think Cho is a Hufflepuff. Seems like it must be Cedric then, but it doesn't really look like him.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Ernie Macmillan could fit, though it doesnt seem to match.

Comment: That's not [Cedric](https://images.app.goo.gl/4Zh3WQZktUdxkNiE8) and the set just lists the figure as "hufflepuff student".

Answer (score 3):

### First row

[image: First row - five figures]

1. **Harry Potter** (glasses)
2. **Ron Weasley** (red hair)
3. **Hermione Granger?** (there's not much to go on, but she should be with Harry and Ron)
4. **Neville Longbottom** (teeth)
5. **Draco Malfoy** (blond hair, Slytherin colours)

### Second row

[image: Second row - four figures]

1. **Parvati Patil** (female, slightly darker skin than the above, Gryffindor colours)
2. ?
3. ?
4. **Luna Lovegood** (blonde hair, Ravenclaw colours)

### Third row

[image: Third row - five figures]

1. **Albus Dumbledore** (white hair and beard, long elaborate robes)
2. **Minerva McGonagall?** (dressed in green with her hair bound back too?)
3. **Severus Snape** (black hair and robes, grumpy expression)
4. **Remus Lupin** (thin moustache)
5. **Argus Filch** (grey colours, Filch's hair)

### Fourth row

[image: Fourth row - three figures]

1. **Lord Voldemort** (green suit, no hair, grey colored skin.)
2. **Bellatrix Lestrange** (that hair and dress sense is unmistakable)
3. **Dolores Umbridge** (pink!)

Comment: Hat tip to Anthony Grist for Parvati Patil (we posted almost simultaneously, but originally he identified her and I didn't).

Comment: Dean Thomas is a Gryffindor

Comment: 3rd row 5 is Slughorn, maybe?

Answer (score -3):

Left to right: First row: Harry Potter, Ron Weasley, Hermione Granger, Neville Longbottom, Draco Malfoy
Second row: Parvati Patil, ?, ? Probably someone on the  Slytherin Quidditch team, Luna Lovegood
Third row: Dumbledore, McGonagall, Snape, Lupin, Filch
Fourth row: Voldemort, Bellatrix Lestrange, Dolores Umbridge

My thoughts: Should have added a Death Eater Nanofigure or two.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Your answer agrees, albeit with less detail and no explanations, with the accepted answer, so it doesn't really add anything.  Please don't post duplicate answers unless you have a large amount to add.  If you like an answer, you should upvote it; if it has issues, comment on it.  You should consider taking the [tour] to learn more about the site.